# How can I call a specific class that is often used in my DOM. jquery

Tags: jquery, class, each

I try to find a way with jquery, to if i click on a div the children div-class should get rid of the class "disable".

For example:

```
<div class="onclick">
    <div class="Infobox disable"></div>
</div>
<div class="onclick">
    <div class="Infobox disable"></div>
</div>
<div class="onclick">
    <div class="Infobox disable"></div>
</div>
<div class="onclick">
    <div class="Infobox disable"></div>
</div>
```

And thats my jquery:

```
$('.infoBox').each(function(){
    $('.onclick').click(function(){
        $('.infobox').removeClass('disable');
    });
});
```

This works, but after click, every infobox div removes class disable, but I wan't that if i click on the first onclick div, only the first div with the class infobox gets rid of the class disable

I don't want to give the infoboxes further classes to seperate them.

Is there any possibility, to solve the problem?

greetings timothes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.onclick').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.infobox').removeClass('disable');
});
```

Your code:

```
$('.infobox').removeClass('disable');
```

will remove the `disable` class from all the divs. You need to use the `div` which have been clicked in the current scope using the `this` keyword, to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the `Infobox` element which is inside the clicked `onclick` element, also you have a spelling error in `Infobox` (small `i`).

Your code is not working because if the case problem, even if it is fixed when you click on one `onclick` element the `disable` class will be removed from all `Infobox` elements because of the global selector `$('.Infobox')`

it should be

```
$('.onclick').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.Infobox').removeClass('disable');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.InfoBox').each(function(){
    $('.onclick').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('disable');
    });
});
```

Please try this.

Comment: `this` is then accessing the wrong element, OP wants the child.